# A Maclaurin expansion of $\arccos(-z)$ using only non-negative coefficients

Tags: taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series, inverse-function

I am trying to express the function $ f(z) = \arccos(-z), \lvert z \lvert   \leqslant 1  $ with a Maclaurin expansion using only non-negative coefficients in a compact form of $ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n,              a_n\geqslant0 $ (1)

From trigonometric identities and standard expansion of arccos/arcsin in infinite series with binomial coefficients it seems easy as $$ \arccos(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2(2k+1)}x^{2k+1}$$ and substituting $x$ with $-z,$ yields
$$f(z)=\frac{\pi}{2} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2(2k+1)}z^{2k+1}$$ 
**However, even if this expansion is using only non-negative coefficients is not exactly as in (1).
Any hints?**

*As suggested i used the transformation* $n=2k+1 \Rightarrow $
$$ f(z)=\frac{\pi}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n-1)!}{2^{n-1}(\frac{(n-1)!}{2!})^2n}z^{n} = \frac{\pi}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^3}{2^{n}(n-1)!n}z^{n} = \frac{\pi}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{3-n}}{n!}z^{n} $$ 
which is closer but not the same

Comment: Transform 2k+1=n, the even coefficients are 0

Comment: @vvnitram, did the transformation, but i dont think is in the form of (1)

Comment: because the sum is not over N. a_n=0 for all n even

Comment: @vvnitram thank you for your answer/tip / it seems that currently i am being total dummy / have to contemplate harder to understand what are you suggesting ...